# Fastest way to read data from XML to show in website

Tags: php, xml, mongodb, postgresql

I have multiple XML files, containing millions of records (10million+). I am trying to figure out a way to allow users to search across these files and present the data in a web page, allowing them to also sort, filter and report on the data.

I am trying to figure out the best way to do this and interested in ideas.

I thought of structuring the data into Postgres or even MongoDB. However, given the nature of the data, I might have to do this refresh once a week.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an XML database, for example eXistDB, MarkLogic, or BaseX.

Comment: Thank you, but would an XML database faster than using MongoDB when it comes to reporting and searching the data?

Comment: Like any other database product, XML databases will deliver excellent performance on a wide range of queries, and lousy performance on others, but the queries they are good at are exactly the kind of queries you are likely to want to execute, as far as one can tell from your one-line statement of requirements.